# How to get width of screen in landscape from portrait orientation

Tags: android

It looks easy but it's not. I tried multiple options to calculate width in landscape from portrait, but it look like I am missing some important detail.

So I have this code:

```
  val displayMetrics get() = DisplayMetrics().apply { defaultDisplay.getMetrics(this) }

  val realDisplayMetrics get() = DisplayMetrics().apply { defaultDisplay.getRealMetrics(this) }

  val navigationBarHeightLandscape: Int
    get() {
        val heightId = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("navigation_bar_height_landscape", "dimen", "android")
        if (heightId.isSet) return resources.getDimensionPixelSize(heightId)
        return 0
  }

  fun calculateLandscapeWidthFromPortrait(): Int {
    return realDisplayMetrics.heightPixels - navigationBarHeightLandscape
  }
```

Basically it seems displayMetrics differs for portrait and landscape while I cannot get from portrait information how it will be modified in landscape.

Comment: As a workaround after some week of research and debugging I just gave up, I force ui to landscape, measure it and show dialog informing user that app needed to measure ui in landscape then when he click ok I unset the forced orientation. It's not so bad , I could do it like this after one day maybe and not try so hard to fight android UI.